# Open and view and/or edit check 21 image file

Tags: java, php

Does anyone have a library or have a way in PHP or JAVA to view, edit or break down x9.37 files also known as check 21 image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The X9.37 Java Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/x937/) may fit your needs.

It was the third hit on Google for x9.37.